# How do I deploy Jupyter to Medium? "AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, deployment, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to deploy Jupyter Notebook to Medium with jupyter_to_medium and still getting the same error. Have tried both Safari and Chrome. I have integration tokens.

MacBook Pro mid 2017

```
Failed to post to Medium
Returned error message below

"AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_bundler.py\", line 37, in upload
data = publish(**kwargs)
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_publish_to_medium.py\", line 299, in publish
chrome_path, save_markdown, table_conversion)
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_publish_to_medium.py\", line 41, in __init__
self.nb = self.get_notebook()
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_publish_to_medium.py\", line 76, in get_notebook
return nbformat.read(self.filename, as_version=4)
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py\", line 141, in read
return reads(fp.read(), as_version, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read'
"
```

Comment: This question is a bit sparse - what other information could you provide to a reader to help them replicate the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same error in Python3.7. Here is what worked for me:

The failure cause by this function call `reads(fp.read(), as_version, **kwargs)  in File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py\".` 
Apparently, `fp` is a path `string`, you cannot use `read()` directly on it.

Changes:

Add the following lines before it:

```
text = None
with open(fp, 'r') as f:
     text = f.read()
```

and update the original line

```
return reads(fp.read(), as_version, **kwargs)
```

to

```
return reads(text, as_version, **kwargs)
```